# trying to pass params to elasticsearch getting null_pointer_exception

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to send to Elasticsearch the following query. Here is the most minimal update by query which gives me the exception.  Lets name it Query1:

`{
  "id": "someID",
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": " if (ctx._source.containsKey('value')) { ctx._source.value = ctx._source.value + params.value; }"
  },
  "params": {
    "value": 1
  },
  "upsert": {
    "value": 1
  }
}`

Been trying to hunt down this issue for a while now. In our case the parameter value is indexed as an `integer`.  The query it's self is being sent as part of a bulk API. Which looks like as a following:

`{update: {_id:"someID", _index:"someIndex", _type:"someType"}}
(Query1)`

when trying to run the script it will have a run time exception:
null_point_exception

`params.value 
      ^--- here`

I've seen [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336532/nullpointerexceptions-when-accessing-elasticsearch-painless-scripted-metric-aggr?noredirect=1#comment94976717_53336532) issues to this one but non which contains solutions. In stack overflow and other sites.

Comment: looks like params is collection of fields and other stuff, you may access to your data like this `params._fields['fieldName'].value`

Comment: Testing just that.

Comment: params._fields still gives me null pointer exception

Comment: well, could you give my set of mapping / data.. i will try my best to investigate your issue

Comment: thanks @Yanis-git can't wait.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Asked in the elastic forum. params wasn't inside script.

Comment: Link to the thread?