# String query in Elasticsearch returns values without the queried field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents in ES with some fields, and "team" field. The "team" field is always checked, and usually some other fields. The problem is when I check for some non-existing field, I get a lot of results. E.g. query like this:

```
GET localhost:9200/index/_search

{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "(asdf:Ssdfdfdf) AND team.keyword:(\"my-team\")"
        }
    }
}
```

Returns thousands of results, and obviously, none of them contains field `asdf`

What do I need to set to get rid of such results?

EDIT:

I tried with `"explain": true` and this is what I got:

```
            "_explanation": {
                "value": 8.43526E-4,
                "description": "weight(team.keyword:my-team in 9) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": 8.43526E-4,
                        "description": "score(doc=9,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 8.43526E-4,
                                "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 592.0,
                                        "description": "docFreq",
                                        "details": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 592.0,
                                        "description": "docCount",
                                        "details": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "value": 1.0,
                                "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1) from:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.0,
                                        "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                        "details": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.2,
                                        "description": "parameter k1",
                                        "details": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 0.0,
                                        "description": "parameter b (norms omitted for field)",
                                        "details": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

EDIT 2:

The document I uploaded:

```
{
  "first_name":"Paweł",
  "last_name":"Stawicki",
  "height":180,
  "birth_date":"28/01/1979",
  "team":"my-team",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Lidka",
      "metrics": [ 0.38, 1.33, 0.3, 0.32 ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Tymek",
      "metrics": [ 5.3, 0.2, 3.22, 4.00, 5.02 ]
    }
  ],
  "relation": "capsule"
}
```

EDIT 3:

Index settings:

```
{
  "test_index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "birth_date": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "children": {
                    "properties": {
                        "metrics": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "height": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "last_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "relation": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "team": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1587478667465",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "ziQLIaqUQcSOtpokChzGCg",
            "version": {
                "created": "6070099"
            },
            "provided_name": "test_index"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I also noticed some strange thing. I have 2 instances of ES. One of them misbehaves (returns document even when querying by non-existing field), on the other it doesn't, no documents returned when non-existing field is in the query.

Comment: Could you share some sample docs that mis-matched? The mapping too please.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix the query string with an `_exists_` subquery to double-check and pre-filter the non-applicable docs out:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "_exists_:asdf AND asdf:Ssdfdfdf AND team.keyword:(\"my-team\")"
    }
  }
}
```

Although this should not be necessary since you've already got an AND query in there...

Comment: This works, however, I can't solve the problem like this. The part in parentheses (`(asdf:Ssdfdfdf)`) is filled in by user in the form on the page. We just add the team.keyword part for performance and security. I can't parse the text user enters to find fields names and add them to `_exists_`

Comment: I used the mapping from EDIT 2, synced the example doc and used your query. It does not return anything (as it should). Are you 100% sure that there are no other queries may be interfering with the `query_string`? Also, from your provided `_explain` response, only the `team` information was explained -- nothing about the non-existent asdf... If modifying the query string is not possible, would it be possible to add `"minimum_should_match": 2` below the `query` part?

Comment: I guess it must be something in ES settings then. I also have second ES instance where it works fine. I even checked the ES version, but both instances are 6.7.2

Comment: With `"minimum_should_match": 2` and non-existing field, nothing is matched. With existing field and valid value, also nothing. Only with removed field and `team` left it matches 2 documents

Comment: I see. I didn't mean that the problem is w/ ES itself but rather the query payload you're sending... What happens if you recreate a test index from scratch in the env where this error occurs? Same scenario?

Comment: I did just that. I created the index in the env where error occurs, and reproduced the error. It os on our company DEV env. Locally, on my machine, the error does not occur.

Comment: Got it. Could you share the index config? `GET indexname`

Comment: Added as "EDIT 3"

Comment: Thanks. Nothing suspicious there. I'd recommend doing a fresh reinstall of 6.7.2 and if the error still happens, open a GH issue. I too experienced a situation of an inexplicable ES error in only 1 specific (minor) release of ES -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/53336532/8160318

Comment: Turned out it's bug in 6.7.0. And there was 6.7.0 on DEV, not 6.7.2. I must have checked it wrong :/ https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/41022

Comment: Got it. OK yea the whole thing sounded fishy so I’m glad the error was recognized and fixed.